# ¿Por qué no funciona fflush en este caso?

Tags: c

Estoy estudiando C y he llegado al apartado de las estructuras. Estoy viendo este código de ejemplo y a la hora de introducir el segundo nombre se saltaba el `fgets`. He buscado por internet y he encontrado la solución que pongo a continuación, creando un string y absorbiendo lo que queda en el buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int edad;
    char nombre[50];
    char puesto[50];
}registro;

int main(){
    registro r1, r2;
    char arreglo[100];

    printf("REGISTRO 1\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fgets(r1.nombre, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("PUESTO: ");
    fgets(r1.puesto, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("EDAD: ");
    scanf("%i", &r1.edad);
    gets(arreglo);

    printf("REGISTRO 2\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fgets(r2.nombre, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("PUESTO: ");
    fgets(r2.puesto, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("EDAD: ");
    scanf("%i", &r2.edad);

    printf("\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS REGISTRO 1:\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: %s", r1.nombre);
    printf("PUESTO: %s", r1.puesto);
    printf("EDAD: %i\n", r1.edad);

    printf("\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS REGISTRO 2:\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: %s", r2.nombre);
    printf("PUESTO: %s", r2.puesto);
    printf("EDAD: %i\n", r2.edad);

    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo si en vez de hacer eso empleo la función `fflush()` no funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int edad;
    char nombre[50];
    char puesto[50];
}registro;

int main(){
    registro r1, r2;

    printf("REGISTRO 1\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fgets(r1.nombre, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("PUESTO: ");
    fgets(r1.puesto, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("EDAD: ");
    scanf("%i", &r1.edad);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("REGISTRO 2\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fgets(r2.nombre, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("PUESTO: ");
    fgets(r2.puesto, 50, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("EDAD: ");
    scanf("%i", &r2.edad);

    printf("\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS REGISTRO 1:\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: %s", r1.nombre);
    printf("PUESTO: %s", r1.puesto);
    printf("EDAD: %i\n", r1.edad);

    printf("\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS REGISTRO 2:\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: %s", r2.nombre);
    printf("PUESTO: %s", r2.puesto);
    printf("EDAD: %i\n", r2.edad);

    return 0;
}
```

La pregunta que me surge es la del título: ¿por qué no funciona con `fflush` cuando para los strings lo utilizo sin problemas?

Comment: @trauma gracias por tu respuesta. No conocía la web a la que haces referencia así que me la apunto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fflush` únicamente debería utilizarse con *streams* de **salida**. El estándar es muy claro al respecto: usar `fflush` con *streams* de entrada es un comportamiento indefinido, es decir, depende del compilador que te funcione de una forma o de otra.

Si quieres descartar lo que haya en `stdin` puedes recurrir al siguiente bucle:

```
for(int ch; ch != EOF && ch != '\n'; ch = fgetc(stdin));
```

Lo que hace es, básicamente, ir extraer caracteres de `stdin` hasta que se encuentra un salto de línea o si llega al final del *stream*

Comment: entiendo a grandes rasgos lo que hace ese for que me comentas pero lo que no entiendo es por qué no sigue la estructura típica del for de (inicialización; condición; incremento). Soy demasiado novato en esto de C. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @pablo42malaga ya está corregido, perdona. Realmente el compilador no comprueba que lo que has puesto en cada parte del for es lo que se espera. El compilador simplemente espera instrucciones en esas tres secciones y, con ellas, compone el bucle

Comment: gracias. Por ahora estoy empezando con C y eso se nota en que mis preguntas pueden ser un poco básicas. Un saludo.