# ¿Cómo funciona el fflush(stdin) o el setbuf(stdin, NULL) en C?

Tags: c, while, cmd

Tengo que hacer un programa en C que sume los cuadrados de los distintos valores que asigne el usuario con una estructura do-while, pero el programa termina unos segundos después de ingresar tan sólo el primer valor.

Lo primero que pregunta el programa es la cantidad de números que se van a ingresar (que se guarda en int i) y, posteriormente, con la do-while se van preguntando por estos números (float x) para luego sumar sus cuadrados (float x2).

Compilo todo por el cmd y, por lo que entendí, se supone que tanto el fflush(stdin) y/o el setbuf(stdin, NULL) sirven para limpiar el buffer y así poder seguir escribiendo, pero me encuentro con el problema de que no me permite hacer eso. Es decir, después de asignar el 1er número (o valor para x), en lugar de preguntarme por el 2do, 3er... número, termina el programa.

Adjunto el código completo por si es que el error no está en el setbuf(stdin, NULL).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int i = 0;
    float x, cont, x2;
    float n = 1;
    cont = 0;
        printf(" Indique cuántos números va a ingresar: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        do
        {
            setbuf(stdin, NULL);
            printf(" Indique el %2.0f° valor de x: ", n);
            scanf("%f", x);
            x2 = x * x;
            cont = cont + x2;
        }
        while(n <= i);
        printf(" La suma de los cuadrados es %f", cont);
    return 1;
}
```

Agradecería mucho me pudieran indicar en qué me estoy equivocando y cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

No veo que el programa se cuelgue. [Esto](https://tio.run/##bVFBTsMwELz7FaugorSEqgR6gRYJcUKKuHFCCBnbaS25Njh2sVT1MfyAM0f6sLBO2xAq9uLJjGczu2anM8bq@khqpjwXk8pxaYbza9IyyjCqRKSI1A4WVOo0AmpnLAM2pxYGiJePT31CVgSwKuG2rrS4fb4pigySpH/VSNEpYQqj7WepDHUQsI/RLoOQd2mN9862RJR/XbFeLbYq0wTuNJdvXgDzmw/tTAV687UQFsGSAsUfzqyoqL2EfYQmIaMazT2eZHAsOwI3LVy1aDfTiy/TuB@dwf1DUXRc/wYSCnr5cFR@f2ISZSxwAQFjZKAPrPs0JWrhQAs5zh1gAOEvv9tIc5y0i4u1btH7XOIbaJhMoTtjm7SgUPkFjcEU7ot5yi3liEQFTZjYfWe0wnmr43us63pMzkhOzskFGZMf) es lo que puedo reproducir.

Lo que sí veo es que entra en un bucle infinito porque nunca aumentas la variable `n`.

El otro inconveniente es que debes pasar la dirección de memoria de `x` al `scanf`. Esto lo puedes hacer con el [operador `&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of).

---

En cuanto a `fflush(stdin)`, ya hay una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/547430/169744). También puedes consultar [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Básicamente, para streams de entrada su comportamiento no está definido. Es decir, no deberías usar `fflush(stdin)` ya que no es portable.

[`setbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) sirve para cambiar el buffer usado por el stream.

`setbuf(stdin, NULL)` deshabilita el uso del buffer y probablemente no necesites hacer eso. Si en un stream quedan caracteres molestando, debes consumirlo. Puedes usar [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) o [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) con ese propósito.

Comment: Ya quedó el programa, muchísimas gracias. No me había percatado de que olvidé el operador & en el scanf y que la variable n debía irse incrementando de uno en uno (n++).